# Install Arch Linux alongside Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux

I have a windows 8.1 on which I installed Ubuntu 12.04 (dual OS). Now I also want to install Arch Linux alongside windows and ubuntu. Please tell me the how to do this on Ubuntu. I have a gparted Partion Editor. Also I installed the Arch linux which took me 24 minutes. But uploading it is taking forever. Am I on the right track? Please explain what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Arch is installed at this point and you don't see it, then you only need to add a grub entry for Arch so that Grub would redirect you to the OS.

If it is not installed, then you should follow the Arch installation guide up to the point of configuring GRUB and then you could check the GRUB page on the ArchWiki especially the dual booting section:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Dual-booting

Comment: : Thanks. I don't think it is completely installed. Since 3 hours, 43 MB/553 MB has been installed. But it  was downloaded in 24 minutes. But can you tell me in layman's terms what GRUB is, and do I run those commands in the terminal? I am very new to these.

Comment: GRUB is a bootloader. It is responsible for loading the OS(kernel), so if you have more than one OS installed, it will have a list of these with their specific configurations... As a matter of fact, you can use GRUB's console to load your OS manually. You can find the configuration of that on your /boot.

Answer (score 0):

You have windows, its not important. You have ubuntu. after installing arch, you can go to ubuntu and perform

```
#update-grub
```

grub will be smart enough to detect the existing arch installation using OS Prober. Boot via grub > choose arch